# How to implement the EVM Trait for a Substrate Runtime?

Tags: rust, ethereum, substrate, parity-io, evm

Following the [adding a module to your runtime](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/adding-a-module-to-your-runtime), I'm trying to implement the [Parity Substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) `paint-evm` trait for the [Dothereum Runtime](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/tree/beta/runtime).

The [EVM module trait](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/srml_evm/trait.Trait.html) is defined as follows:

```rust
pub trait Trait: Trait + Trait {
    type FeeCalculator: FeeCalculator;
    type ConvertAccountId: ConvertAccountId<Self::AccountId>;
    type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>;
    type Event: From<Event> + Into<Self::Event>;
    type Precompiles: Precompiles;
}
```

The *adding a module* tutorial here, however, is a bit vague and encourages one to:

> ".. explore the source code of the [..] module if things don't make sense .."

While the EVM module code doesn't seem too complex, I fail to understand how to implement the EVM trait for my runtime:

```rust
impl evm::Trait for Runtime {
    type FeeCalculator = ();
    type ConvertAccountId = ();
    type Currency = Balances; 
    type Event = Event;
    type Precompiles = ();
}
```

What types do `FeeCalculator` and `ConvertAccountId` expect here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because pallet-evm doesn't provide default implementations for the types you need, you'll need to create them yourself.

```rust
use paint_evm::{FeeCalculator, ConvertAccountId};
use primitives::{U256, H160};

pub struct FixedGasPrice;

impl FeeCalculator for FixedGasPrice {
    fn gas_price() -> U256 {
        // Gas price is always one token per gas.
        1.into()
    }
}

pub struct TruncatedAccountId;

impl<AccountId> ConvertAccountId<AccountId> for TruncatedAccountId {
    fn convert_account_id(account_id: &AccountId) -> H160 {
        //TODO just truncate the fist several bits and return the resulting H160
        // Or maybe hashing is easier to figure out
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl paint_evm::Trait for Runtime {
    type FeeCalculator = FixedGasPrice;
    type ConvertAccountId = TruncatedAccountId;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type Event = Event;
    type Precompiles = (); // We can use () here because paint_evm provides an
                           // `impl Precompiles for ()``
                           // block that always returns none (line 75)
}
```

I look forward to improving this answer as I understand more myself.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That answers my question. Coming up with a dynamic gas pricing would be a good next excercise.