# How to implement the ethereum virtual machine pallet?

Tags: substrate

Im trying to implement the pallet_evm to my substrate runtime
i've seen this handy instruction but the types have changed
[How to implement the EVM Trait for a Substrate Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942015/how-to-implement-the-evm-trait-for-a-substrate-runtime)

```
impl FeeCalculator for FixedGasPrice {
    fn min_gas_price() -> U256 {
        // Gas price is always one token per gas.
        1.into()
    }
}
parameter_types! {
    pub const ChainId: u64 = 43;
}
impl pallet_evm::Trait for Runtime {
    type FeeCalculator = FixedGasPrice;
    type CallOrigin = EnsureAddressOrigin<AccountId, Success = AccountId>;
    type WithdrawOrigin = EnsureAddressOrigin<AccountId, Success = AccountId>;
    type AddressMapping = AddressMapping<AccountId>;
    type Currency = balances::Module<Runtime>;
    type Event = Event;
    type ChainId = ChainId;
}
```

how do we implement this pallet now with rc-5?

Comment: This example may be helpful https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/runtime/src/lib.rs#L267

Comment: Your starter template is even better https://github.com/danforbes/substrate-evm

Comment: That's great to hear! Unfortunately that template isn't up-to-date. Were you able to get things figured out for `rc5`?